# Wordpress после апдэйта плагинов выдаёт ошибку

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Wordpress v4.9.4 шаблона Brooklyn 3.3.3 после апдэйта плагинов better-wp-security wordfence wordpress-seo,выдаёт ошибку: Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp() in /usr/local/hosting/home/nameofweb.net/web/www/wp-blog-header.php on line 16

Как решить ?

Comment: посмотри что там за код

Comment: @PauloBerezini то что и написано: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/4.9/src/wp-blog-header.php

Comment: Не знаю, как вы там обновляли, но, похоже, грохнули папку /wp=includes